# The type or namespace name 'Application' does not exist in the namespace 'WebApplication1.Models'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Hi I am new to Net Core and I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVkdrusLaQsfERmL_Jh4XmU) tutorial from PragimTech. In extending IdentityUser Part(77) of tutorial when I create new Class for ApplicationUser in order to extend from IdentityUser I face a Compile error saying

> type Application  does not exist in namespace

. There are my codes to show.

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {

    }
}
```

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using WebApplication1.Models
@using WebApplication1.ViewModels
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

**The ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs file**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConnection"))
          );
        services.AddMvc(config => {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
        services.AddScoped< IEmployeeRepository, SqlEmployeeRepository> ();
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
        }).
            AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
    }
```

**The injection part in _layout.cshtml**

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signeInManager;
```

**AccountController**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
                            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
        }


        [AcceptVerbs("Post","Get")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task< IActionResult> IsEmailInUse(string email)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

            if(user == null)
            {
                 return Json(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json($"Email {email} is already taken.");
              }
         }

         [HttpGet]
         [AllowAnonymous]
         public IActionResult Register()
         {
             return View();
          }

         [HttpPost]
         [AllowAnonymous]
         public async Task< IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
         {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
              {
                 var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                 var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                 if (result.Succeeded)
                 {
                     await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                     return RedirectToAction("index","home");
                      }
                  else
                {
                     foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                     {
                         ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                     }
            }
        }
        return View(model);
         }

         [HttpGet]
         [AllowAnonymous]
         public IActionResult Login()
         {
             return View();
          }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, 
               model.RememberMe, false);
              if (result.Succeeded)
              {
                   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                   {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }else 
                     return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid user or password");
                  }
              }
               return View(model);
         }

          [HttpPost]
          public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
          {
              await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
              return RedirectToAction("Index", "home");
           }

             }
```

Comment: According to your codes,  I don't find you have used application type or namespace. Could you please tell me which line you has thrown this error ?

Comment: I imported the namespaces inside _viewImport.cshtml; as you see there is @using Webapplication.Models that is for Models namespace and my ApplicationUser class is inside Models folder. I even used WebApplication.Models.ApplicationUser inside injecting tag but the same error happend. The error is inside SignInManager inside _layout.cshmtl

Comment: Could you please share the the codes which is related with SignInManager inside _layout.cshmtl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Cleaned the solution and re-built it.